# Is WebRTC Conference possible in Star Topology with html5-JS client?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, webrtc

To Connect **10 people** in WebRTC Audio/Video Conference, it **requires 90 calls in Mesh-Topology** (Each Peer should connect with all other Peers in Conference). If number of participants are more the bandwidth consumption is more for each user. 
Is There any way to make WebRTC conference **in Star-Topology**(i.e. **conferencing 10 people with 10 Calls**) from browser client without any Hardware Like MCU?

My Requirement is Initiate Audio Conference 'n' people with n calls:
Moderator initiated 3 calls from WebRTC browser client to different users(A,B,C)
with 3 different peer connections. Now Moderator can able to here/speak with all three. Now Moderator Want to Conference all Three(A RemoteStream.AudioTracks to B&C, B Audio-Tracks to A&C, C Audio-Tracks to A&B). Without any new peer connections from A,B,C.

Is it Possible to mix audio tracks in Chrome/Firefox ......?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am answering my old question (posted when i was an Amateur WebRTC Programmer).

The Solution is using WebAudio API, available in both Chrome & Firefox.

Here the great post by WebRTCHacks  [Mixing Audio in browser](https://webrtchacks.com/web-audio-conference/)

It explained everything step by step.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, exactly what you described is possible in Firefox by using the WebAudio API. At the current time it is not possible in Chrome because it cannot create a MediaStreamAudioSourceNode from WebRTC streams (I hope this limitation will go away soon). Thus, the moderator's browser must be Firefox. The other peers can use other browsers.

This way you can set up a conference call with 10 peers, all of them only connecting to the moderator, thus using only 10 WebRTC connections.

What you have forgotten to mention is that you also have to mix in the moderator's audio for each peer.

With the WebAudio API you also could do some fancy things like per-peer audio visualization, muting, volume control, mixing in of audio files, etc.

Comment: Is there some example of how WebAudio could be used for such mixing? Will this be separate audio stream for each peer, or this mixing could be done once for all 10?

Comment: You have to generate one separate mix for each peer, consisting of all _other_ peer's audio plus moderator's audio, to avoid that a peer hears an echo of him/herself. Basically, for each peer you have to generate one `MediaStreamAudioSourceNode` from the incoming audio, and one `MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode` which will be the outgoing mix. You then use `.connect()` to mix peer sources into the peer destinations. I suggest JS objects for peers. Mozilla has the API's documentation online. I have implemented this successfully and it's running in produciton, however I yet have to document it.

Comment: I am looking foward to learn from your experience  @MichaelFranzl  as I too have experimented with many to many - but it was just too much load.

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC gives you the possibility to stream audio to somewhere. Whether that "somewhere" is a server or another client is up to you and does not depend on the protocol. For your scenario, what needs to be built, is a central box that implements moderator control and executes audio mixing.

Comment: Is there any way to mix audio Tracks in javascript or html5?